# Performing a simple migration in Realm

Tags: android, migration, database-migration, realm

I am testing Realm db for my next Android app and I want to do a simple migration. I got a bit confused looking at the documentation.

I have this simple class User:

```
public class User extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
private String name;
private int age;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

and I want to add (via migration) an additional field to the table User called "phoneNumber". I don't understand how/where I can initiate the migration? I am creating the schema in the application onCreate method like that:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .schemaVersion(0)
                .migration(new MyMigration())
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
}

}
```

and my migration class:

```
public class MyMigration implements RealmMigration {
@Override
public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
    // DynamicRealm exposes an editable schema
    RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

    // Migrate to version 1: Add a new class.
    // Example:
    // public Person extends RealmObject {
    //     private String name;
    //     private int age;
    //     // getters and setters left out for brevity
    // }
    if (oldVersion == 0) {
        schema.create("User")
                .addField("name", String.class)
                .addField("age", int.class);
        oldVersion++;
    }

    // Migrate to version 2: Add a primary key + object references
    // Example:
    // public Person extends RealmObject {
    //     private String name;
    //     @PrimaryKey
    //     private int age;
    //     private Dog favoriteDog;
    //     private RealmList<Dog> dogs;
    //     // getters and setters left out for brevity
    // }
    if (oldVersion == 1) {
        schema.get("User")
                .addField("phoneNumber", long.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED);
        oldVersion++;
    }

    Log.d("MainActivity","Migration happend!");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
    // DynamicRealm exposes an editable schema
    RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

    // This is the current schema version before migration.
    if (oldVersion == 0) {
        schema.get("User")
            .addField("phoneNumber", long.class, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED);
        oldVersion++;
    }

    // More migrations (for version 1->2, 2->3, etc..) in the future.
}
```

And create `RealmConfiguration` like below:

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .schemaVersion(1) // This the expected schema version after migration.
            .migration(new MyMigration())
            .build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

Comment: When I use this the compiler complains that "The value changed at 'oldVersion++' is never used and my version is never incremented. Any ideas?

Comment: The incremental of `oldVersion` is only used to handle multi migrations inside the `migrate`. eg. when you have a new migration 1->2, the code in block `if (oldVersion == 0)` doesn't have to be changed, just add a new block `if (oldVersion == 1)`. You can just ignore the lint warning or comment out `oldVersion++` before you have another migration. What do you mean "my version is never incremented"? If there is no exception happen, after successfully open the first Realm instance with `.schemaVersion(1)`, you db should be at version 1. Can you set a BP in the `migrate` to see what happens?

Comment: With the code above my migration is never called. I put a System.out.println at the top of my Migration.class and it is never called with the above method

Comment: If it is newly installed ---- the old Realm db file doesn't exist, migration won't be called. if it is your case?

Comment: apologies for the slow reply. yes the old realm db exists and has data stored in it. The exception on loading is RealmMigration must be provided

Comment: Did you change the `schemaVersion(0)` to `schemaVersion(1)` in your code?

Comment: I have managed to get realm to migrate from version 0 by using realm = Realm.getInstance(config1); instead of Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config1); but now the app gives a null pointer complaining that "Realm on disk is newer than the one specified: v1 vs. v0". does this indicate it never increased the schema version even though it ran migration?

Comment: `setDefaultConfiguration` should not impact this at all. very strange. Do you have different configurations to open the same Realm?